# Android: Lag setting text to textbox

Tags: android, performance, lag

The program needs to have as little lags as possible. Unfortunately, `inputWord.setText("");` in the code below gives a slight lag. Is there anyway to get around this lag? Help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void addInputWordListener(){
    inputWord.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().equals("")){
                topView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                return;
            }

            if (s.toString().endsWith(" ")){    //submitting a word
                token = s.toString().trim();
                System.out.println("1");
                if (token.equalsIgnoreCase(topView.getText().toString())){
                    System.out.println("2");
                    inputWord.setText("");
                    System.out.println("3");
                    topView.setText(midView.getText());
                    System.out.println("4");
                    midView.setText(botView.getText());
                    System.out.println("5");
                    botView.setText(MainMenu.we.nextWord());
                    System.out.println("6");

                }else
                {
                    topView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                }
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    });
}
```

Here are the LogCat output for suspect run:

```
04-07 02:41:10.539: I/System.out(13152): 1
04-07 02:41:10.539: I/System.out(13152): 2
04-07 02:41:10.549: I/System.out(13152): 3
04-07 02:41:10.549: I/System.out(13152): 4
04-07 02:41:10.549: I/System.out(13152): 5
04-07 02:41:10.549: I/System.out(13152): 6
```

Comment: Take out the log statements.  Logs are actually pretty slow.

Comment: Are you referring to the System.out.println's? I'm sorry..those were meant to track which operation was making the code laggy. It was between 2 and 3

Comment: Are you referring to the System.out.println's? I'm sorry..those were utilized to track which section of the code was taking the most time to execute, since LogCat has highly granular time tracking; and so I used those println's to mark timestamps for relative lag locating. I've summarily concluded that the lag exists between printlns "2" and "3".

Comment: Hi user1363410, just wondered if any of the answers were helpful? If so, it would be helpful to those who wrote them if you could tick / upvote them; if not if you could clarify why not they may be able to help you more :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `System.out.println`, these are seriously affecting your 'performance'.

Answer (score 0):

See if anything changes after replacing `inputWord.setText("");` with `s.clear();`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also speed things up by doing the conversion to String only once:

```
 String inputString = s.toString();
```

Then use inputString for all the comparisons

You could also cache the text on the TextViews (ie keep a copy in the activity) to save having to do all the getText() calls.

Answer (score 0):

You have just been catched by the [Observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28information_technology%29).

As already Gabe Sechan said, Logs are slow and also time shown by them might not be accurate.

Try using SystemClock.uptimeMills() before and in the mid and subtract and print them after if you really need, but time differences less then few milliseconds won't be accurate at all.